# JSF 2 custom composite component with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, event-handling, custom-component, composite-component

I'm trying to create a custom composite component colorPicker using this jQuery plugin http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/.

I´d like to be able to append a jsf tag `f:ajax`, and when a color is selected, perform an ajax call to the server. I have been testing this functionality and it all appears to be right, but obviously I missed something, because the listener is never called.

This is my component code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<composite:interface>
<composite:attribute name="label" />
<composite:clientBehavior name="customEvent" event="change" targets="#{cc.clientId}"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="colorpicker/colorpicker.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="colorpicker/layout.css" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/jquery.js" target="head"/>
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/colorpicker.js" target="head"/>
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/eye.js" target="head"/>
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/utils.js" target="head"/>
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/layout.js" target="head"/>
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="colorpicker/hex.js" target="head"/>


    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" class="colorSelector">
        <div style="background-color: #0000FF;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>


    //jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery('##{cc.clientId}').ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
          jQuery(colpkr).fadeIn(2000);
          alert('onchange1');
        launchEvent(document.getElementById('#{cc.clientId}'));
        alert('onchange2');
          //return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {


          jQuery(colpkr).fadeOut(2000);
          return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {


        }
      });

    //});

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function launchEvent(fieldName) {
      alert('launchEvent1');
        if ("fireEvent" in fieldName) {
          alert('launchEvent2');
          fieldName.fireEvent("onchange");
          alert('launchEvent3');
    } else {
      alert('launchEvent4');
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    alert('launchEvent5');
      evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
      alert('launchEvent6');
      fieldName.dispatchEvent(evt);
      alert('launchEvent7');
    }
        /* ]]> */
}

  </script>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

And this is the page implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:r="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/seam/faces"
      xmlns:cp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component">

<h:head>
   <title>Test</title>  
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <f:view>
    <h:form prependId="false">
      <cp:colorpicker id="colorSelector">
        <f:ajax event="customEvent" listener="#{themeBean.changeColor1}" onevent="alert('event raised');"/>
      </cp:colorpicker>
      <h:inputText value="#{themeBean.color1}"></h:inputText>
    </h:form>
  </f:view>
</h:body>       

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` can only be attached to a [`ClientBehaviorHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) such as `<h:inputText>`. A plain HTML `<div>` isn't such one component. You basically need to have a HTML `<input>` element, not a `<div>` element. Even more, how would you otherwise set the submitted value in the bean?

```
<cc:interface>
    ...
    <cc:clientBehavior name="customEvent" targets="input" event="valueChange" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    ...    
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />

    <h:outputScript>
        jQuery("[id='#{cc.clientId}:input']").ColorPicker({ 
            // ...
        });
    </h:outputScript>
</cc:implementation>
```

*(please note that I fixed the jQuery selector as well; this way the JSF client ID separator `:` will be taken into account properly instead of malforming the CSS selector)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your usage of `<f:ajax onevent>` is wrong. It should point to a function reference, it should not contain some function calls. The proper usage is

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="functionName" />

...

<h:outputScript>
    function functionName(data) {
        alert("Event " + data.status + " raised");
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

#### See also:

- [ajax call in jsf 2.0 (myfaces), the onevent Javascript function in the ajax tag gets called before the rendering is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350769/ajax-call-in-jsf-2-0-myfaces-the-onevent-javascipt-function-in-the-ajax-tag-g/11351236#11351236)