# jsf + js dynamic graph

Tags: javascript, jsf, graph

I want to make dynamic charts with google API, populated with JSON data from servlet.

On a page I have selectManyCheckbox:

```
                <h:selectManyCheckbox id="xxx" value="#{panelB.foo}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{panelB.fooList}" var="s"
                                   itemLabel="#{s}"
                                   itemValue="#{s}"/>
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@this :graphs"/>
                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

And below I have a div for script,and script itself:

```
<h:form id="graphs">
        <div id="graph">
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

and script part, responsible for getting JSON data from servlet:

```
  $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/graph/get/#{panelB.makeQuery()}/'
         };
```

this method : `panelB.makeQuery()` just takes the fooList and makes a string for servlet.

When I enter the page, this method is called, and it's working correctly, but when I click on any checkbox, the graphs disapear, and method `makeQuery()` is never invoked.

I tried:
-changing render on selectMany
-adding onevent="drawCahrt()"

nothing works. Please help. Thank you

Comment: have you got only one graph on this page or multiple?

Comment: one graph that changes when checkbox is clicked

Answer (score 0):

How about using HTML5 data attribute.

```
<h:form id="graphs">
    <div id="graph" data-graph="#{myBean.selectedItem.graphData}">
    </div>
</h:form>
```

then you could select `data-graph` with [jQuery](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/01/working-with-html5.aspx), pass it to your chart drawing function and finally relounch `drawCahrt()` with (if using Primefaces).

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="xxx" value="#{panelB.foo}">
   ....
   <p:ajax oncomplete="drawChart();" process="@this" update=":graphs" /> 
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Make sure you put you ajax scriptlet in a place that is being rerendered by your , and call drawChart() after update of HTML DOM based on ajax response.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I'm not using Primefaces, and project I'm working on don't want primefaces. I'm sorry, the problem with rendering non JSF tag is pure mistake - it should be render="graphs" :)

Comment: you don't have to use Primefaces, i'm always using it this way, `<f:ajax>` will do as well.

Comment: ok, i guess i did not get your intentions at first. You are displaying more or less data in your chart depending on how many checkboxes you tick, right?

Comment: right - checkboxes determin how many data I want to dipslay, servlet prepare data from database, and suplies JSON for graphs engine. With static data it work just fine.

Comment: it's got to work. the question is why is `drawChart()` not being triggered by `<f:ajax render=":graphs" event="click" onevent="drawChart()" />`. have you tried using `change` as event?

Comment: I think I desribed my problem wrong: `drawChart()` is being triggered, but it don't want to update parameters for servlet. It only reaches to `makeQuery()` once - during first loading of page, after that it only work on the first set of data - but data change with every click on checkBoxes. Yes - I tried event="change"

Comment: first of all, make sure you are updating your JS function, then there is this nice answer from [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350769/ajax-call-in-jsf-2-0-myfaces-the-onevent-javascipt-function-in-the-ajax-tag-g) about invoking callback only on complete - like `oncomplete` inPrimefaces, third give HTML5 `data-attr` a chance.

Comment: `$.ajax({ dataType: "json",
         url: 'http://localhost:8080//graph/get/{panelB.makeQuery()}/',
         success: function (data) {`
As you can see I already check for right status, the js function is invoking and is doing it's job - make's a graph. But on invoke event this function do not connect to the given URL to update status list - it just render the same graph that on load. how this function should work:
-when called, `drawChart` should connect with servlet, get new set of data formated in JSON
-make a graph from recived data

Comment: what drawChart does: it connects to servlet ONLY one time - on load. Recived data, makes graph. On event when it's called second, thuird and more times, it DOES NOT connect to servlet to update data - it just redraw the chart with data from first and the only connection

Comment: is `$.ajax(...` in a separate JS file? does path differ, do you update this script?

Comment: and you are sure you rerender it?

Comment: no - the function is not rerendering and that is ,what I think, a problem. If the function rerender, it would update the path for servlet, and donwload accurate data

Comment: wha does {panelB.makeQuery()} evaluate to? a link to graph json?

Comment: so it should change every time you tick a checkbox, right? so make sure you put this scriptlet in a place that is being rerendered by your `<f:ajax>`, and call `drawChart()` after update of HTML DOM based on ajax response.

Comment: I'm testing it right now. It looks much better - the request to servlet is updated, and the method from bean is invoked. So it looks nice. Thank you

Comment: post your answer as a 'answer' so I could vote it up