# Display progress bar while AJAX call

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to display some progress bar at the corner of the web page during AJAX call. I noticed that when Internet connection is slow user can't see that there is a AJAX call in progress. Is there any solution with core JSF?

Comment: There are events you can catch for the start and end of an ajax call. You know that do you? You can show anything in between those

Comment: @Kukeltje can you show some example please?

Comment: Sorry no, I am lazy. Read the specs of the f:ajax tag http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkddf.html check the attributes and search further on google or stackoverflow. This is all so basic and easy to find via searchengines

Answer (score 2):

You could use `onevent` attribute on `f:ajax`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{ajaxTestBean.myAction}">
        <f:ajax onevent="myFunc"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(ajaxObj){
        if('begin' == ajaxObj.status){
            //Start or Show your Spinner
        }else if('complete' == ajaxObj.status){
            //Stop or Hide your Spinner
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here `myFunc` will usually gets called 3 times.

- On Start of Ajax request [`status=='begin'`].
- On Complete of Ajax request [`status=='complete'`]
- On Complete of Ajax request wit the
  result [`status=='success'`]

Comment: How I Can create progress bar like this? https://salt.bountysource.com/

Comment: @PeterPenzov: By trying, banging your head, learning and asking detailed questions, not 'homework' ones. And the basic answer is already in this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350769/ajax-call-in-jsf-2-0-myfaces-the-onevent-javascipt-function-in-the-ajax-tag-g

Comment: Where did you read about `status=='failed'`? This doesn't exist.

Comment: @BalusC : Oh yes its not there. I'll remove it from answer. Thanks.